# What is the difference between &self and self?

Tags: rust

It is unclear for my what difference between `self` and `&self`!
Because in my example both work.

Comment: What example do you mean? It's hard to answer this question in such a general way.

Answer (score 5):

`&self` The `variable` created with the struct/enum is borrowed by the function means the the ownership is not given. The function in which the `variable` is created will have the ownership.

`self` The ownership is transferred and the variable is destroyed after execution of the function

```rust
struct User {
  name: String,
  id: i32
}
impl User {
    fn print_name(&self) -> () {
        println!("{}", self.name);
    }
    fn print_id(self) -> () {
        println!("{}", self.id);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let me = User { name: "Haider".to_owned(), id: 1234 };
    // me is borrowed so this means the variable is still owned by the `main` function we can call as many as functions until the ownership isn't transferred
     me.print_name();
     me.print_name();
     me.print_name();
     me.print_name();
     // ownership transferred and the `me` is destroyed after the execution of `me.print_id()` we will get error if run any other function on `me`
     me.print_id();
     // Error 
     me.print_name();

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### &self

`&self` is a reference to the instance(object) of a struct that calls it. Is good to know that when you add a method (A function that is used by an instance of a struct) by an `impl` block, you must add `&self` or `&mut self` (`&mut self` means that only mutable instance of the struct can access it`) For example, this is a method:

```
fn a_method(&self){
     //Stuff that goes in a method
}


//When you call it, you can just ignore `&self` or `&mut self`
a_method();
```

### self

`self` represents the instance of a struct.

```
struct animal{ 
age: i32,
name: String
}

impl animal{ //Add methods and function in an impl block
     fn display_name(&self) { //A method 
            println!("Hello, my name is {}.", self.name); //`self` used here to represent that animal (instance of the animal struct)
     }
}

fn main(){ 
      let my_cat: animal = animal{age: 32, name: "Cat".to_string()}; //Declare an instance of the animal struct
      my_cat.display_name(); //Calling the method
}
```

For the result it should be:

```
Hello my name is Cat.
```

Comment: _"`self` represents the instance of a struct."_ Hmm, no, not really. In `animal::display_name()`, `self` is still a reference (`&animal`). `*self` would "represent" the instance itself.

Comment: _"you must add `&self` or `&mut self`"_ These aren't the only options; you can also accept `self` which will transfer the value into the method.